# Difference between incendiary and normal shotguns shells in Tomb Raider?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I'm playing the game for the first time and want to know if there's a downside to using the incendiary shells.

Answer (score -2):

Don't think so. I had the same question to. I thawt the fire rounds would yes, have the chance of catching the target on on fire, but only by sacrificing damage dealt at the same time. That dusn't seem 2 be the case tho. So, as i do, i just recommend keeping it on ‘incendiary rounds’. I hav also found it kinda pointless 2 giv u a silencer 4 ur pistol later in the game when the whole time u've been using ur bow. Why stop now just 2 use & waste ur pistol ammo on silent kills? Plus u can retrieve ur arrows, unlike w/ the silencer pistol. Only way i can c this EVER cuming n2 play is if u don't hav or just plain run out of arrows. Which i don't c happening. Ammo is actually pretty plentiful 4 the most part.